# 2D box colliders are not working in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Very simple, I created an object that simply serves as a box collider that sits over the background. When the player character runs into it, I want the character to stop, but they just walk right through it. I have both of their colliders set to 2D box colliders, neither of them have the trigger option checked, and both are rigid bodies.

Comment: did you add the rigidbody2d? or rigidbody? having collission issues usually boils down to some form of mismatch

Comment: Also, you probably already ensured that in your Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics -> Layer Collision Matrix, the two used layer types are not unchecked for collisions among each other.

Comment: Please show screen shots of your inspector for both objects.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are using `Transform.position` to move the player.

**All** rigid body objects should be moved using the rigid body specific `rigidbody.velocity` function. Transform.position is practically teleportation while, `rigidbody.velocity` actually moves the `rigidbody` component. Allowing for the 2d colliders to take action.

*Hope this helps!*